# UIView.animate() issue

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

I have a code, where UI elements are changed after user interaction. I use `UIView.animate()` to refresh UI. The code is pretty simple:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
    self.fadeIn()
} completion: { _ in
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
        self.fadeOut()
    }
}
```

Very important point is that total animation duration from beginning to the end should be 2 seconds. But sometimes, there are no UI changes in `fadeIn()`, and `UIView.animate()` just get immediately to completion block. But in that option I want to have a delay for duration time (1 sec), and only after that get to completion block to `fadeOut`. How I can force animate with duration even if it's nothing to animate in animation block? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe don't call `fadeOut()` in the completion block, and just make sure that it's called with one second delay after the `fadeIn()` is called?

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
    self.fadeIn()
} 

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 1.0) {
    self.fadeOut()
}
```